# Adding different strings to legend title in QGIS layer composer depending on which layer is active

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-variable

My QGIS project includes three layers representing catchment areas for playgrounds. Depending on the age of the children, the catchment areas are either 200 m (catch_area_200m.shp), 400 m (catch_area_400m.shp), or 1000 m (catch_area_1000m.shp).

Within the print composer always just one catchment area is visible. Depending on which of the three layers is active, I want to have this information in the title of the legend.

What I basically need is some sort of conditional clause, checking which layer is activated and then printing a string with the appropriate distance, e.g. '400 Meters', to the title of the legend.

How can this be realised?

Comment: This would be an if-clause on a substring of the layer-name - the biggest issue (for me) is how to get the name of the active layer.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using the function `is_layer_visible` in an expression.

In your *Legend > Item proprieties* select the *Data Defined Override* on the right of the title and, then, *Edit...*

[image]

Here you can use this expression

```
case 
when is_layer_visible('poly') then concat ('100m')
when  is_layer_visible('poly 2') then concat ('200m')
else ''
end
```

Change the name on the layers (here `poly` and `poly 2`) with yours.

Now, the legend title will be depending on the activated layer.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. When I search for the function 'is_layer_visible' nothing appears (QGIS 3.4.4). It is supposed to be listed within the "General"-section of the field calculator? Or is a plugin required?

Comment: The function is part of the QGIS core. And it is available on 3.4 (see documentation here https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html?highlight=is_layer_visible). It is on General and available in all the expression and data defined override options. If you are using on the legend title it should be selectable.